# Why does the integral of the surface area of a sphere equal its volume?

Tags: volume, area

Why does the integral of the surface area of a sphere equal it's volume?

$$\int{4\pi r^2 \ \mathrm{d}r =\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3}$$

I don't quite understand why the relationship between surface area and volume is this way. Is this true for any other shapes?

Comment: True for circles as well.  Area = $\pi r^2$.  Circumference = $2\pi r$.  So here's the question: does it hold for all $n$-spheres?  Other kinds of surfaces?

Comment: Integrating the surface equation gives you the volume that the surface encloses like when you integrate the function of a graph you obtain the area under the curve.

Comment: So would this apply to say a square-because integrating 6x^2 doesn't give me x^3

Comment: I'm sorry... I meant a cube. Clearly it's too late for math. :)

Comment: If you consider the radius of a cube to be the distance $r$ from center to middle of a face, then its volume is $(2r)^3$ and its surface area is $6(2r)^2$.  Integrate from $r=0$ to $r=r$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure some will have an issue with the technical aspects of the following explanation, but I believe that it should intuitively help.

One way to think about the area under a curve (and the definite integral), is to picture a vertical line from the horizontal axis to the graph of your function.  Starting at say $x=0$, picture this line moving to the right.  As it does, and its height changes, it will touch along the way a set of points in the plane (shaded below).  Perhaps think about this line as being covered in paint, and as it moves along it paints the area under the curve.
[image]

You can view the definite integral $$\int_0^xf(t)dt$$ as suggesting the motion of this line of changing height on the horizontal axis from 0 to $x$ and giving you the area of the region that it "paints".

The same thought process works for other shapes.  Consider a square centered at the origin.
[image]

The perimeter of this square is $8x$.  Think of $x$ starting at zero and increasing.  As the square increases in size, its perimeter will also "paint" a collection of points in the plane, and we can think about the area of the square as being the painted points.  In the same vein as above, the integral $$\int_0^x8tdt=4x^2$$ suggests the painting of these points and gives us the area of the resulting collection of painted points (you can easily see that $4x^2$ is the area of the shaded square).

Likewise for a circle when integrating the circumference gives the area: $$\int_0^r2\pi tdt=\pi r^2$$

Three dimensional shapes are a little harder to picture (and definitely harder to draw), but you can think about them in the same way.  Extending the square example to a cube, we can now think about the faces of the cube (its surface area) as "painting" a volume of points.  Consider a cube centered at the origin, with the horizontal axis going through the center of opposing faces.  The surface area of such a cube is $24t^2$ (check) when it has "radius" $t$.  Integrating $$\int_0^x24t^2dt=8x^3$$ gives the volume of points touched by the faces of the cube as it expands from radius 0 to radius $x$.

Hopefully, by using the same sort of thought process on a sphere, you'll find that it makes a little more intuitive sense that the integral of its surface area gives us its volume.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is essentially the same as the reason why the volume of an onion is the same as the volume of all its layers. Imagine a spherical ball as being composed of many thin spherical layers, like an onion. The volume of the layer between radius $r$ and radius $r+\delta r$ is (to a close approximation if $\delta r$ is small enough) the area $4\pi r^2$ times its thickness: $4\pi r^2\cdot\delta r$. Summing all these small volumes from the centre of the ball ($r=0$) to its outer radius ($r=a$, say) and taking the limit as the $\delta r$ tend to $0$ gives us the limit
$$\int_0^a 4\pi r^2\mathrm dr.$$As you know, this evaluates to $\frac43\!\pi a^3$, the volume of the sphere.